# Vertex coordinates of selected vertices not updating, but indices update

Tags: vertices, coordinates

I am writing some code that selects the end vertices of an open tube, and then saves the indices and coordinates in a list so I can use these points to bridge edge loops.

```
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
bpy.context.tool_settings.mesh_select_mode = (
    True, False, False)  # vertex select mode
bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='DESELECT')
bpy.ops.mesh.select_non_manifold()
obj = bpy.context.edit_object
me = obj.data
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)
for v in bm.verts:
    if v.select:
        both_ends_A.append([v.index, v.co])  
n = int(len(both_ends_A)/2)
print("num of vertices on each end is " + str(n))
print("printing both ends.." + str(both_ends_A))
```

My problem is that sometimes the list ends up having the same coordinate for every single vertex (even though indices are different).
So it will print something like [[212, Vector((0,0,0))], [312, Vector((0,0,0))] etc
The coordinate is not always repeated and it is not always 0.

Update: here is an example output I get:

```
num of vertices on each end is 4
printing both ends..[[0, Vector((1.4617953300476074, -1.0000001192092896, 1.0000001192092896))], [1, Vector((1.4617953300476074, -1.0000001192092896, -1.0000001192092896))], [2, Vector((1.4617953300476074, 1.0000001192092896, -1.0000001192092896))], [3, Vector((1.4617953300476074, 1.0000001192092896, 1.0000001192092896))], [192, Vector((2.8763275146484375, -1.0000001192092896, 1.0000001192092896))], [193, Vector((2.8763275146484375, -1.0000001192092896, -1.0000001192092896))], [194, Vector((2.8763275146484375, 1.0000001192092896, -1.0000001192092896))], [195, Vector((2.8763275146484375, 1.0000001192092896, 1.0000001192092896))]]
cursor coord<Vector (1.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000)>
coordinate is <Vector (1.4618, -1.0000, 1.0000)>
[0, Vector((1.4617953300476074, -1.0000001192092896, 1.0000001192092896)), 1.4877013825667318]
coordinate is <Vector (1.4618, -1.0000, -1.0000)>
[1, Vector((1.4617953300476074, -1.0000001192092896, -1.0000001192092896)), 1.4877013825667318]
coordinate is <Vector (1.4618, 1.0000, -1.0000)>
[2, Vector((1.4617953300476074, 1.0000001192092896, -1.0000001192092896)), 1.4877013825667318]
coordinate is <Vector (1.4618, 1.0000, 1.0000)>
[3, Vector((1.4617953300476074, 1.0000001192092896, 1.0000001192092896)), 1.4877013825667318]
coordinate is <Vector (-114974916608.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000)>
[192, Vector((-114974916608.0, 8.96831017167883e-43, 5.605193857299268e-45)), 114974916609.0]
coordinate is <Vector (-114977275904.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000)>
[193, Vector((-114977275904.0, 8.96831017167883e-43, 5.605193857299268e-45)), 114977275905.0]
coordinate is <Vector (-114979635200.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000)>
[194, Vector((-114979635200.0, 8.96831017167883e-43, 5.605193857299268e-45)), 114979635201.0]
coordinate is <Vector (-114981994496.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000)>
[195, Vector((-114981994496.0, 8.96831017167883e-43, 5.605193857299268e-45)), 114981994497.0]
vertices loop for bridging:[0, 1, 2, 3]
loop [[0, Vector((0.0, 1.0, 1.0))], [1, Vector((0.0, -1.0, 1.0))], [2, Vector((0.0, -1.0, -1.0))], [3, Vector((0.0, 1.0, -1.0))]]
```

Somehow the coordinates of vertices 192 - 195 change and the X value is WAY too high, and they all have the same coordinates.
In this case the original both_ends list was ok but sometimes all the coordinates were 0,0,0 in there as well. It seems to be really inconsistent.

The object is centered at the origin so I don't think the problem has to do with transforming coords from local to global (especially because even in local CS the different points should have different coordinates).

The off thing is that sometimes the coordinates do update and are correct, it is just inconsistent, and the vertex IDs always remain correct

Comment: Hello, It's really hard to say without seeing more of your code / project. Might be you actually have double vertices on the same location, or you manipulate both_ends_A beforehand, or the context is incorrect causing desync ? You can try throwing a `me.update()` after the select manifold operator or going out and in edit mode which normally refreshes the mesh

Comment: Thank you very much! I checked and there are no double vertices, and I didn't manipulate the list beforehand, I will try the me.update(), thank you!

Comment: I added an example output to the question

Comment: @Gorgious could you explain a bit what the me.update() does? adding it after the select manifold wouldn't work because I haven't created the me yet. Should I be creating this before the non manifold operator? Thank you!

Comment: Oh Okay I see. This is actually a floating point rounding error, since you seem to have very high coordinates in your mesh. Check the origin point and unhide any meshes with ALT H in edit mode to see if there's something weird. Usually anything farther than say 1-10 km to the world origin will start to cause issues

Comment: Thank you! the really large points don't make any sense though, my mesh points are all between 0 and 2, so I am not sure where those large points come from